# Single callback for multiple /proc entries - find the caller entry

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

First of all, the API for /proc (Linux 3.10+) seems to be very different from the one specified in the old kernel books.

I am creating several /proc entries, which have the same write function associated as callback. The same stands for the read function.

If I write or I read one of the /proc entries mentioned above, I would like to know which entry was written or read and I would like to be able to have that information inside the callback function.

I am using `proc_create(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct file_operations *proc_fops)`.

The callback functions have the following list of arguments: `(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offp)`.

I can't figure out what could give me any clue regarding from which file has the call been triggered. First I thought that the `struct file*` might help. I've found that the `struct file` contains a `struct path` which contains a `struct dentry` which contains a `struct qstr` which contains a `const unsigned char *name`.
Is this the way that this thing should be handled or is it an easier, more elegant way (haven't tested the char *name yet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create_data(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct file_operations *proc_fops, void *data)` in your case, which allows you to attach arbitrary private data to each entry and act upon it in your other functions.
You can then implement an `.open` callback in your `proc_fops` struct. This has the signature `int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp);`. Your private data can be accessed by calling `PDE_DATA(inode)` and should probably be copied into `filp->private_data` for later use in other functions that get `filp` and don't get `inode`.